# can't add a loop to the code

Tags: c, loops

User must enter a number between `1` and `9999` (ex. `2345`) and the program should check if the following relation holds:

> (2<sup>3</sup>)+(3<sup>3</sup>)+(4<sup>3</sup>)+(5<sup>3</sup>) = 2345

and also it must check all the numbers from 1 to the number user have entered.

My question is: what's wrong with the loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {    

    int m, j, k, l; int i, q, n;
    printf("Enter a number from 1 to 9999 \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n<1 || n>9999) {
        printf("the number is to low/high \n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        m = i % 10;
        j = i / 10 % 10;
        k = i / 10 / 10 % 10;
        l = i / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10;

        q = pow(l, 3) + pow(k, 3) + pow(j, 3) + pow(m, 3);
        if (q == n) {
            printf("%d \n", q);
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

P.S. :I actually solved this problem a few months ago but I deleted the folder where the problem was, and now I can't figure out how to make this loop work again.

Comment: Well, you should tell us. What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: You should use stdio.h instead of cstdio

Comment: What "does not work" do you get a runtime  error or a value not as expected or is there a compiler error? You need to be specific in your question. Also instead of multiple divides, use a single divide by a constant. (i/100 instead of i/10/10)

Comment: *"I solved this problem ... but I deleted the folder"* many of us learn the hard way: archive your work daily, weekly, etc., on external media.

Comment: Btw, the relation you specified in your question is false: the sum is less than 1000, let alone 2000. In general I didn't find any problems in your code, so it looks like this relation is simply not true for `0 < n <= 9999`.

Comment: @szczurcio He appears to have just picked 2345 as a random example. I see that the maximum q for 9999 is 2916 so he would never get a print out. 2345 would give a value of 224.

Comment: I do not get any error, I do no get any result, like there isn't such a number existing, but I'm sure that there should be like 7 or 8.
my poor english skills won't let me translate this problem, so i'll try to give an example:
user enters 5566, the program should check if the sum of all the figures at ^3 is equal to the number [5^3+5^3+6^3+6^3=5566].
And all the numbers from 1 to the number user have entered must be checked.

Comment: As I said, it appears that there is no such number because the maximum number that you can get is from 9999 which sums to 2916. You can see this by printing the largest q for any number.

Comment: There is no error within your program. You can test it by entering value 27. Although `0^3 + 0^3 + 2^3 + 7^3 != 27` your loop finds a result with `i = 3`.

Comment: example number 153 should be printed, since 1^3+5^3+3^3=1+125+27=153
and the program should check for all the numbers like this from 1 to the number user have entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here, when you're checking the result:

```
if (q == n) {
```

You're checking the result against the top number you've selected, not the current number.

Change it to this to compare against the current number:

```
if (q == i) {
```

With 9999 as input, output is:

```
1
153
370
371
407
```

Comment: thank you very much, finally works (:  and I'm very sorry for creating a new thread just because of this little mistake...

Comment: @SavcaMarin Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to replace the statement,
`if(q == n)` to
`if(q == i)`, reading the comments i think that is what you probably want since entering n =9999, yields
1, 153, 370, 371, 407

Comment: i = 3456;
    m = i%10;
    j = i/10%10;
    k = i/10/10%10;
    l = i/10/10/10%10;
    
    printf("%d %d %d %d", l, k, j, m);
        
tested this, and it works fine, there's something wrong with the loop

Comment: Yup, tested it and your code also works fine, try changing q==n to q==i, i think thats what you want

Comment: thank you very much, and I'm very sorry for creating a new thread just because of this little mistake...